# iOS how can I make undo action for rotating, scaling and adding UIView to UIIMageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` and I can add new items (as a subview) to this `UIImageView` or I can move & rotate the items in `UIImageView`. 
I'm try to make undo actions for this items, so my code;

Before each new actions I get the copy of `UIImageView` and store them in `NSMutableArray`

```
[self.lastActions addObject:[self getCopy]];
```

I get the same UIImageView with different memory address. (I'm not sure this is the right approach)

```
-(UIImageView *)getCopy{
    NSData *archivedViewData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.imageView];
    id clone = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedViewData];
    return clone;
}
```

And when I make the undo;

```
-(IBAction)undoButtonClicked:(id)sender{

    UIImageView *lastImageView = [self.lastActions lastObject];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        self.imageView = lastImageView;
    }];

    [self.lastActions removeObject:lastImageView];     
}
```

But it does not change the UIImageView on screen. 
Any ideas for whats wrong on my code ?

Comment: I think the main `UIImageView` ie `self.imageView` has it already changed transformation, try this `self.imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;` then `self.imageView.transform= lastImageView.transform`;

Comment: What is your nee? change image or imageview

Comment: @iphonic  I try that but it not work

Comment: I am trying this "self. ImageView" is removed virtually from the view. First time only copied the image, second time we not able to retrieve the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

I am try your above idea. Not able to get the output. this is another idea to achieve the same.
I am using image to reveal the image change on the same imageview  "undo" operation. I have implemented like below method.

its working fine in my side.
I hope this will help us.

// Undo button action

```
-(IBAction)undoButtonClicked:(id)sender{
      UIImage *lastImageView =  lastImageView = (UIImage *)[lastActions lastObject];

     if( [lastActions count]!=0) {
           [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
           self.imageView.image = lastImageView;
           }];

           [lastActions removeObject:lastImageView];
      }
}
```

// Copy the image from public variable self.imageview

```
-(IBAction)copyButton:(id)sender{

    [lastActions addObject:self.imageView.image];

}
```

// Random Orientation change to rotate the image.

```
-(UIImageOrientation )randonImageOrientation {

   int min = 0 ;
   int max = 3;
   UIImageOrientation ori;
   int randomNumber = min + rand() % (max-min);

   switch (randomNumber)
   {
    case 0 :
        ori = UIImageOrientationDown;
        break;

    case 1:
        ori = UIImageOrientationLeft;
        break;

    case 2:
        ori = UIImageOrientationRight;
        break;
    case 3:
        ori = UIImageOrientationUp;
        break;
    default :
        ori = UIImageOrientationUp;
        break;

   }
return  ori;
}
```

// below method using to rotate the image

```
 -(UIImage *)imageOrientation :(UIImageOrientation)imageOri image:(UIImage *)oriImage {

   UIImage * LandscapeImage = oriImage;
   UIImage * PortraitImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: LandscapeImage.CGImage
                                                     scale: 0.5
                                               orientation: imageOri];
   return PortraitImage;
 }
```